# I get this report from leak canary, how can I fix the problems identified

Tags: java, android, memory, leakcanary

This is the output from leak canary after running the app. Th code below is the standard log output from leak canary and the references are based on the current app that uses exoplayer to play mp3 audio file

┬───

│ GC Root: Input or output parameters in native code

│

├─ java.util.TaskQueue instance

│    Leaking: UNKNOWN

│    Retaining 528 B in 2 objects

│    ↓ TaskQueue.queue

│                ~~~~~

├─ java.util.TimerTask[] array

│    Leaking: UNKNOWN

│    Retaining 512 B in 1 objects

│    ↓ TimerTask[0]

│               ~~~

├─ com.github.islamkhsh.CardSliderViewPager$SlidingTask instance

│    Leaking: UNKNOWN

│    Retaining 2.0 MB in 13670 objects

│    ↓ CardSliderViewPager$SlidingTask.this$0

│                                      ~~~~~~

├─ com.github.islamkhsh.CardSliderViewPager instance

│    Leaking: UNKNOWN

│    Retaining 2.0 MB in 13668 objects

│    View not part of a window view hierarchy

│    View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)

│    View.mID = R.id.viewPager

│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1

│    mContext instance of com.pkasemer.mwonyaa.RootActivity with mDestroyed =

│    false

│    ↓ View.mParent

│           ~~~~~~~

├─ androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout instance

│    Leaking: UNKNOWN

│    Retaining 1.6 MB in 11594 objects

│    View not part of a window view hierarchy

│    View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)

│    View.mID = R.id.playerView

│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1

│    mContext instance of com.pkasemer.mwonyaa.RootActivity with mDestroyed =

│    false

│    ↓ View.mParent

│           ~~~~~~~

├─ androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView instance

│    Leaking: UNKNOWN

│    Retaining 1.5 MB in 10856 objects

│    View not part of a window view hierarchy

│    View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)

│    View.mID = R.id.main_recycler

│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1

│    mContext instance of com.pkasemer.mwonyaa.RootActivity with mDestroyed =

│    false

│    ↓ View.mParent

│           ~~~~~~~

├─ androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout instance

│    Leaking: UNKNOWN

│    Retaining 3.9 kB in 81 objects

│    View not part of a window view hierarchy

│    View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)

│    View.mID = R.id.main_swiperefresh

│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1

│    mContext instance of com.pkasemer.mwonyaa.RootActivity with mDestroyed =

│    false

│    ↓ View.mParent

│           ~~~~~~~

╰→ android.widget.FrameLayout instance

​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.pkasemer.

​     mwonyaa.Fragments.Search received Fragment#onDestroyView() callback

​     (references to its views should be cleared to prevent leaks))

​     Retaining 2.0 kB in 45 objects

​     key = fe8776a5-8c6c-452c-86ea-f07c94c6c300

​     watchDurationMillis = 19352

​     retainedDurationMillis = 14352

​     View not part of a window view hierarchy

​     View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)

​     View.mWindowAttachCount = 1

​     mContext instance of com.pkasemer.mwonyaa.RootActivity with mDestroyed =

​     false

METADATA

Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 29

Build.MANUFACTURER: INFINIX MOBILITY LIMITED

LeakCanary version: 2.10

App process name: com.pkasemer.mwonyaa

Class count: 16415

Instance count: 216004

Primitive array count: 122153

Object array count: 34818

Thread count: 53

Heap total bytes: 23265560

Bitmap count: 62

Bitmap total bytes: 17227346

Large bitmap count: 1

Large bitmap total bytes: 6553601

Db 1: open /data/user/0/com.pkasemer.mwonyaa/databases/Mwonya

Db 2: open /data/user/0/com.pkasemer.mwonyaa/no_backup/androidx.work.workdb

Db 3: closed /data/user/0/com.pkasemer.

mwonyaa/databases/google_app_measurement_local.db

Db 4: open /data/user/0/com.pkasemer.mwonyaa/databases/Mwonya

Db 5: open /data/user/0/com.pkasemer.mwonyaa/databases/com.google.android.

datatransport.events

Db 6: open /data/user/0/com.pkasemer.mwonyaa/databases/Mwonya

Stats: LruCache[maxSize=3000,hits=69898,misses=182744,hitRate=27%]

RandomAccess[bytes=10784339,reads=182744,travel=58867131075,range=27352144,size=

34355609]

Analysis duration: 91735 ms```

I have tried profiling the app in Android studio and wanted to know why my app keeps crusing. This is the output from leak canary after running the app. Th code below is the standard log output from leak canary and the references are based on the current app that uses exoplayer to play mp3 audio files

Answer (score 0):

mwonyaa.Fragments.Search is leaking memory.

All the lateinit var variables is the cause for memory leaks.

override onDestroyView() in Fragment and make your root view and adapter Null

Example ::

```
private var binding: FragmentABCBinding? = null



 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

  binding = FragmentABCBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

 return binding?.root
}


override fun onDestroyView() {
        myViewModel.job?.cancel()
        binding?.newsFeedRecylerView?.adapter = null
        binding = null
        super.onDestroyView()
    }
```